# Historical Graph To Numbers?

Tags: ocr

Suppose I create a graph of the data:

```
1/1/2001 1
1/2/2001 2
1/3/2001 2
1/4/2001 5
1/5/2001 1
1/6/2001 7
...
```

It may look like this:

```
|
|           x       x
|                   
|        
|    x   x       
|x              x
|          
|------------------------>
```

Now I create a graph with it and then I lose the data, the key. How can you open the lock back to the information from the graph? Is there some OCR software ready on Tessarec built to do that? If I was going to do that on my own, how should I do that?

Solving this problem from ASCII is easier like above, I know how to do the job with it. But how can I deal with pictures not in ASCII? format-ASCII -converters and then analyze the pictures with regex matching? Other tools? Which tools?

Comment: Perhaps related [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5316/which-tools-for-ascii-portfolio-visualization).

Answer (score 1):

If the graph exists as a raster image and is not cluttered with text or clip art, then a small program along these lines:

```
image = Image.open("image.gif")
for x in x_axis_range:
   for y in y_axis_range:
      if image.getpixel((y,x)) == BLACK:
         data_point[scale_x(x)] = scale_y(y)
```

Adjust x_axis_range and y_axis_range not to include the axises.
Adjust functions scale_x and scale_y to match the actual axis scales.
Adjust the black-test to accommodate errors due to image compression.

Comment: If there are a lot of images of different size or scaling, this approach of manually adjusting the algorithm may not be practical.

Comment: The above code is a python snippet using PIL (Python Imaging Library) but it is also pseudocode for the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues did something similar with a software called [DataThief](http://www.datathief.org/), so you might want to try that. I have not used it personally, but it seems to do the job.